# How may I use VlookUp with approximate date ranges?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have this data.

| Code | Beg. date | End date | Class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54 | 01/03/2021 | 10/10/2020 | 166 |
| 54 | 11/10/2021 | 31/12/9999 | 322 |
| 102 | 10/04/2020 | 31/08/2021 | 180 |
| 102 | 01/09/2021 | 30/06/2022 | 190 |
| 102 | 01/07/2022 | 31/12/9999 | 200 |

I need to find the class of this range

```
102 | 01/05/2021 | 31/05/2021
```

The answer is 190 because it is within the fourth range in the data.

I need to know how to make this kind of Vlookup to match with approximate dates and the code as a second condition.

I tried to use Vlookup and Match but didn't get result for the immediate superior value.

I tried to concatenate code with Beg. Date and use VlookUp and AND.

Comment: What is your exact excel version?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not helping here... just curious, how a range of time  `May 1st 2021 to May 31st 2021` is within the range of time `Sep 1st 2021 to Jun 6th 2022` ? Shouldn't it be in the range `Apr 10th 2020 to Aug 31st 2021`, hence the expected result is 180 ? Please CMIIW.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly ....

[image]

Column F1, G1, H1 is the criteria to be searched

```
Sub test()
Dim rgData As Range: Dim rg As Range
Dim rgBeg As Date: Dim rgEnd As Date
Dim dBeg As Date: Dim dEnd As Date
Dim rgCod As Integer

Set rgData = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
rgCod = Range("F1").Value
rgBeg = Range("G1").Value
rgEnd = Range("H1").Value

    With rgData
        .Replace rgCod, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        Set rg = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical).Offset(0, 1)
        .Replace True, rgCod, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
    End With
        
    For Each cell In rg
        dBeg = cell.Value: dEnd = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        If rgBeg > dBeg And rgEnd < dEnd Then MsgBox cell.Offset(0, 2): Exit For
    Next
    
End Sub
```

But the message box will show the result 180, because 1-May-21 to 31-May-21 is within the range 10-Apr-20 to 31-Aug-21.

The code is just making a range which contains the code to be searched (in this case : 102), by replacing "102" into TRUE, set the cells which has TRUE value into rg variable, then put back "102" from TRUE.

Then it loop to each cell in the rg variable, making the dBeg as the beginning date and the dEnd as the end date. Then it compare if rgBeg is bigger then dBeg and rgEnd is less then dEnd... then the msgbox show the result which is the looped cell.offset(0,2) value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365 or Excel 2021, you don't need VBA at all for this - just use the **FILTER** function.

Assuming your table top left is on A1, and your 'search criteria' are in F1:H1, then the following formula, entered in `I1` will find the class for you:

```
=FILTER(D:D,(G1>=B:B)*(H1<=C:C)*(A:A=F1))
```

[image]